# PostCSS modules are loading from the wrong directory

Tags: windows, node-modules, postcss, postcss-cli

I'm trying to get PostCSS CLI to work on Windows, to use with PHPStorm. I've got it working via command line options, but I want to use it with the javascript config file.

Here are the commands I used to install PostCSS through NPM:

```
# NPM is installed at PostCSS\node\npm. Commands are run in the PostCSS dir.

"node\npm" install --global postcss-cli # PostCSS\node\node_modules\postcss-cli\
"node\npm" install --global lost        # PostCSS\node\node_modules\lost\
# and a few other modules...
```

So I've got about 6 modules are in the node/node_modules directory now.

I have this batch file (split into multiple lines for your viewing pleasure). This is in the PostCSS folder, just for testing:

```
"node\postcss" -u postcss-normalize
               -u postcss-cssnext 
               -u postcss-import
               -u lost
               -o output.css
               source.css
```

This batch file works, and all of the plugins work too.

## My problem:

I want to use postcss.config.js, instead of command line parameters, so that I can customize the plugins easily and make it even more portable. I have dozens of separate projects that I will use the same settings for in different directories and computers. So to do that, I've got a new batch file called "run-from-config.bat" with the following content:

```
"node\postcss" -c "postcss.config.js"
               -o output-configured.css
               source.css
```

This new batch file is in the same folder as the command line version, along with the new file **postcss.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-normalize')({
        "browserslist": "last 2 versions" // I intend to add more options...
    }),
    require('postcss-cssnext')({}),
    require('postcss-import')({}),
    require('lost')({})
  ]
}
```

This follows the instructions on the PostCSS-CLI page under "Content": https://github.com/postcss/postcss-cli

But it gives me an error, and appears to be loading modules from the wrong location:

```
    Processing source.css
    { Error: Cannot find module 'postcss-normalize'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (G:\Dropbox\Web Development\PostCSS\postcss.config.js:3:5)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        at requireFromString (G:\Dropbox\Web Development\PostCSS\node\node_modules\postcss-cli\node_modules\require-from-string\index.js:27:4)
        at G:\Dropbox\Web Development\PostCSS\node\node_modules\postcss-cli\node_modules\cosmiconfig\lib\loadJs.js:11:15 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

So it seems it can't find the module when using this javascript config file. But it can when loading plugins through the command line option `-u`. I simply don't know how to change the module directory.

I tried using some other options to change the directory, including `-b` and `-d`, but nothing seems to work. And I just don't understand PostCSS (or the underlying javascript software) enough to debug the problem on my own.